# C++ forget to declare variable type causes error

Tags: c++, class, scope

I'm confused why the following code cannot compile because of the following bug: `'rootLevel' was not declared in this scope`.

In my understanding, the `struct NodeLevel` is declared and defined before `class Solution`, is this not a sufficient condition for this class to be available to the `Solution` class?

Thanks!

```
struct NodeLevel{
    int level;
    BinaryTreeNode * node;
    NodeLevel(int val, BinaryTreeNode * x) : level(val), node(x) {}  
};

class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> levelOrder(BinaryTreeNode* root) {
        queue<NodeLevel> q;
        rootLevel = NodeLevel(0, root);
        q.push(rootLevel);

        /*
        do some stuff with the queue 
        */
    }
};
```

Comment: `NoteLevel rootLevel = NodeLevel(0, root);`

Comment: Too many little weirds in the code. By the time I cleaned up to get a [mcve], I'd reflexively fixed the bug.

Comment: The first usage of `rootLevel` is `rootLevel = NodeLevel(0, root);` .   This does not declare it as a variable - it is a statement that, if `rootLevel` is declared, uses it, but (unlike some other programming languages) does not declare the variable.     Either change that line from `rootLevel = NodeLevel(0, root)` to `NodeLevel rootLevel = NodeLevel(0, root)` (in C++11 and later this can be `auto rootLevel = NodeLevel(0, root)`)  or (more simply as it explicitly avoids creating an object then copying it) `NodeLevel rootLevel(0, root)`.

Comment: @user4581301 It's a typo. I was trying to delete the original comment line but left out a "/" there.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the detailed reply! I'm not familiar with C++ enough and obviously sometimes still forget to declare the variable type. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is correct, you did not declare the variable `rootLevel`.

Comment: I think, next time at least, instead of pointing that it's wrong (as you can see by the question) please, at least correct the code and not just copy paste it...

Comment: Well, I don't think you can correct the code if you don't understand the intent. I was asking about the purpose of that code block.

Comment: Even though asking for the purpose of the code is a good practice, and it's actually better than just going in your own direction. That should have been a comment. Also, the code is simple enough to see that he was just missing the variable declaration as stated in the error `'rootLevel' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I was trying to solve this problem : https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/description/ and this code is part of the set-up :-) I omit the #include statements and the algorithm part to make the matter simpler...